# A conceptual question regarding suspended ring inside vertical inductor coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Suppose a metal ring is suspended inside a vertical inductor (with an elastic string ) when the circuit is open.  When the circuit is closed, does the metal ring tend to jump up or fall down?  Why?

I tried to check the magnetic polarities.  Initially similar polarities seem to be induced on the near sides of the ring and the end of the inductor, like S-S and N-N, so there will be repulsion at both ends.  In such a case what should the motion of the metal ring be?

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit is closed and a DC current is flowing, the metal ring will fall down slower than the case with zero DC current, as the induced current inside metal ring will produce opposite polarity of magnetic field to partially cancel the gravity.

If the circuit is closed with a AC current flowing, similar things happen, but you could have the metal ring floated with appropriate inductor coil design and frequency and magnitude of current. You can check the technique of magnetic levitation.